# Get URL parameter - sharepoint

Tags: list, url, sharepoint

I am trying to extract an ID from my URL and paste it in the sharepoint List into the ID text box, I have tried it like that:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
            return sParameterName[1];
            }
    }
}​
   document.forms['aspnetForm'].ctl00_m_g_d9f5e4f9_7e05_4a4d_88b7_a6b1dcdda667_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField.value=GetQueryStringParams(‘ID’);
</script>
```

however it does not work, my URL:

```
http://Lists/Systems%20Survey/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://Lists/Systems%2520Survey/overview.aspx&ID=14-01234
```

I have put it as a web part xml on my web.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong? :)

thanks for assistance

Answer (score 0):

Use the function below as `getQueryVariable('source')`

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and I have modified:     document.forms['aspnetForm'].ctl00_m_g_d9f5e4f9_7e05_4a4d_88b7_a6b1dcdda667_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField.value=getQueryVariable('ID'); - but still no success... :(

Comment: Can you check if your textbox is not being set or value is not correctly returned ?

Comment: hmmm lets start if value is correctly returned... I can probably display result on my xml web part but how? (sorry for obvious question probably)

Comment: First you can log it in console, like console.log("test"); I hope you know how to open console window on IE/chrome

Comment: found it <a href="javascript:alert(qsValue('myQSParameter'));">Display my query string value</a>

Comment: yes, console is working console.log("test")
test VM3079:2
undefined

Comment: when I added <a href="javascript:alert(getQueryVariable('variable'));">Display my query string value</a> I see no value